# upgrade to macOS Sierra breaks vim

Tags: bash, vim, terminal

On the bash command line, in Terminal, I edit unicode text files in vim, often 1MB per file. This is command line vim, not not mvim or gvim.

One of my Macs runs OS X El Capitan 10.11.6. Two others, I have upgraded to OS X Sierra 10.12.5.

All computers have exactly the same .vimrc file (12655 abbreviations) and I vim-edit the same size of files on both computers.

Before the upgrade, vim performed on all Macs with no perceptible difference: "iab"s were reliably substituted in real time as I typed them, exactly as I specify in my .vimrc file.

But now on the upgraded (Sierra) machines, frequently my "iab" abbreviations are not converted to the proper value.  If I re-save the file I'm editing,  :w, then the "iab" substitution works again.

On the El Capitan machine, performance is as before.

I never experienced these problems with vim before upgrading to Sierra.

Has anyone experienced this? Is there a fix? What causes this?

Incidentally, the alpine command-line, text-based email client also has problems on the machines that were upgraded to Sierra.  Something in the unix shell seems to have been broken by the macos upgrade.